# two class reference eachother , how to do Not.LazyLoad in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

i have two class

```
 public class ProInfo
{
    public ProInfo()
    {
        ProPrices = new List<ProPrice>();
    }
    public virtual Guid ProID { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProCate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual string PicName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Memo { get; set; }
    public virtual bool DeleteFlag { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastUpDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ProPrice> ProPrices { get; set; }

}

 public class ProPrice
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AreaInfo AreaInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ProInfo ProInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual Decimal Price { get; set; }


}
```

mapping codes are :

```
    public ProInfoMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ProID);
        Map(x => x.DeleteFlag);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.PicName);
        Map(x => x.ProCate);
        Map(x => x.Unit);
        Map(x => x.LastUpDateTime);
        HasMany<ProPrice>(x => x.ProPrices);


    }

 public ProPriceMap()
   {
       Id(x => x.Id);
       Map(x => x.Price);
       References<ProInfo> (x => x.ProInfo);
       References<AreaInfo>(x => x.AreaInfo);
   }
```

what i want is to   disable the proprices's lazyload(), so i can get all the prices for the product from database. but, when i change the onetomany to this: `HasMany<ProPrice>(x => x.ProPrices).Not.LazyLoad()`, it cause an Infinite loop.  what do i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, where exactly the loop comes from, but your bidirectional association may cause this. You should declare one side as Inverse(). This can only be done in ProInfoMap, because it is a one-to-many relationship with a bidirectional association:

```
HasMany<ProPrice>(x => x.ProPrices).Inverse().Not.LazyLoad();
```

Try that. It may remove the infinite loop.